# How can build a basic logon page using ASP.NET 4.0 using Active Directory?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, active-directory

I am trying to build a very basic website using ASP.NET to allow users access the private information by logging into the company Active Directory. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: @JonH: Did not get your message. Could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 7):

You will want to set up configuration in the web.config file to tell the ASP.Net app to use forms authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>
```

Then you will need to create a membership provider that will connect to AD for authentication.  Fortunately Microsoft has provided an AD membership provider out of the box, so you can use that.  If you set it as the defaultProvider, ASP.Net will automatically use it for authentication.

```
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider"
         type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
            connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" 
            connectionUsername="<domainName>\administrator" 
            connectionPassword="password"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Finally, you will need to set up a connection string to connect to your domain controller:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ADService" connectionString="LDAP://myCompany.com/DC=myCompany,DC=com"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

[Look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx#paght000022_usingtheactivedirectorymembershipprovider) for a good reference with more details.

Comment: Thank you @Joe. I did come across this article. It is very complicated. Any other recommendation?

Comment: It really is pretty straight-forward. You dont't need to write any code, you can get everything working declaritively by putting the three XML elements I listed above in the web.config file.  I think that article goes into a lot more detail than you need just to get the basic AD authentiation up and running.